# Cloud container clusters create `compute.networks.get` permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create a cluster with GKE. I have a project I have been using already.

When I run

```
gcloud container clusters create cluster1
```

I get the following:

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects//global/networks/default'.

The same thing happens when I use the web UI. Both my service account and my user have owner roles.

I have tried the following to get the cluster create command to work:

1. I tried adding a policy binding for the project for my existing service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <my-project> \
    --member serviceAccount:<my-user>@<my-project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role  roles/compute.admin
```

2. I read enabling the container api service was required

`gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com`

3. Started over. I deleted the service account, created a new one and activated the creds with:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account <my-user>@<my-project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
```

4. I also tried authenticating with my account user:

```
gcloud auth login
```

None of these work and I can't create a cluster

Comment: Are you using a shared VPC?

Comment: 1) Where are you trying to create a cluster? From your desktop (outside Google Cloud) or from the command line running in a Compute Engine instance? 2) `gcloud auth login` uses your user credentials (someone@example.com). 3) You need both `roles/compute.admin` and `roles/container.admin`

Comment: I assigned roles compute engine admin and kubernetes engine admin to my root user even though I have ownership of the project. I still cannot create a basic cluster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I will answer my own question here. From [service account docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)

> When you create a new Cloud project using GCP Console and if Compute Engine API is enabled for your project, a Compute Engine Service account is created for you by default. It is identifiable using the email:

PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

I had delete the default created service accounts somehow and possible the associated roles. I think this is why I couldn't create a cluster under my project anymore. Rather than try to figure out how to recreate, I decided it was best to just start a new project. Afterwords, the cluster create API and console work just fine.

Comment: You did the right choice. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts) advises against recreating a deleted service account.

Comment: this is exactly the problem, the 403 error isn't returned for you making the original container create call, it is returned by the compute API because the container service account does not have the correct permissions. You should have 2 service accounts, the one you mentioned and another container-robot account

Comment: Expanding on @PatrickW comment above... see my posted answer about the SA `...@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. (BTW, it's `container-engine-robot`, not exactly spelled as `container-robot`.)

Answer (score 2):

Debug:

```
gcloud container subnets list-usable --project service-project --network-project shared-vpc-project
```

If you get warning in output:

```
WARNING: Failed to get metadata from network project. GCE_PERMISSION_DENIED: 
Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 
'projects/shared-vpc-project'
```

It means your google managed gke service account in host project doesn't exist.

To solve go to host project apis and enable Kubernetes Engine API. If it's enabled, disable it and enable again back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the compute engine service account permission:

```
 gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <my-project> \
--member [PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--role  roles/compute.admin
```

Comment: I'm sorry this didn't work for me. My user has complete ownership already. There is something else going on. Thinking about just deleting the project and starting over.

Answer (score 0):

While all existing answers are true, I suppose, they are not necessarily complete. The complete list of permissions (that are specific for GKE on Shared VPC) is here:

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc

Search for the string `@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` for the easily-neglected permissions.

For my specific scenario, I was trying to create a GKE Autopilot cluster (which is different from the original poster's Standard cluster). I had to go into the **Host Project** to grant the IAM roles

- `Compute Network User` (`roles/compute.networkUser`)
- `Host Service Agent User` (`roles/container.hostServiceAgentUser`)

to the following GCP-automatically-created "robot" SA (belonging to the **Service Project**):

- `service-<SERVICE-PROJECT-NUMBER>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Recall that the original error message (see the original post) was complaining about some `Google Compute Engine...`, I was misled to focus on the Default Compute Engine SA. I'd never have guessed that it's about the `container-engine-robot` SA.

P.S. To view IAM permissions for that "robot" SA, you need to tick the checkbox `Include Google-provided role grants` like this:

[image]